# Kernel of Permuation Representation is Subgroup of Identity Coset?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is probably really basic, but here it goes

Let K be a subgroup of some group H; let X be the set of left cosets of K, i.e. X={hK:h∈H}; and let G be the group of permutations of X. For all h∈H, let f(h)∈G be the permutation of X that sends every coset h′K to the coset hh′K.

Now I know that Ker(f)={h∈H:haK=aK for every a∈H}=⋂a∈Ha−1Ka is a normal subgroup of H. What I don't understand is why (as my text claims) Ker(f) is contained in K.

Answer (score 0):

Observe $k\in\ker f\implies kK=K \implies k\in K$.

(Also notice $K$ is one of the sets you're intersecting in $\displaystyle\bigcap_{a\in H}aKa^{-1}$.)

Comment: Thank you. The insight about intersection makes sense. As for the first line though wouldn't you have k ∈ ker  f ⟹ kaK = aK ?

Comment: @FrancisHWhite You have $kaK=aK$ *for all* $a$. All $a$. That means *in particular* we have $kK=K$.

Comment: very helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

$\ker(f)=\{h\in H : a^{-1}ha\in K\ \forall a \in H\}$ implies that $\ker$ is contained in $K$ as if you will take $a=e$ (as you see it is for all $a\in H$), it clearly implies that any element of $\ker$ lies in $K$ (as $hK=K \implies h \in K$).